# connection pooling What are removeAbandoned?

Tags: database, jdbc, connection-pooling

What are abandoned connections? What will happen if I will set 
removeAbandoned = false?

Thank You!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Abandoned connections are the connection used by application to do some task but application missed to close them or there was some exception in the process that they weren't closed.

Setting `removeAbandoned = false` might result in out of connections error because there are so many connections in abandoned state then your application will run out of connection. There won't be any connection available to perform the task.

Setting `removeAbandoned = true` will close the connection after the time limit set for `removeAbandonedTimeout`.

This issue arises because of connection leaks in the application.

As per [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) page:

> (boolean) Flag to remove abandoned connections if they exceed the
>   removeAbandonedTimeout. If set to true a connection is considered
>   abandoned and eligible for removal if it has been in use longer than
>   the removeAbandonedTimeout Setting this to true can recover db
>   connections from applications that fail to close a connection. See
>   also logAbandoned The default value is false.

Comment: does busy connection considered abandoned if it runs for too long? e.g. suppose I have removeAbandonedTimeout = 60 and query runs for 61s, will this connection get closed as abandoned before the query returns the result?

Comment: @skwisgaar did you find an answer to your good question?

Comment: Seems like busy connections would be considered abandoned, see the docs [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#:~:text=javax.sql.PooledConnection-,removeAbandoned,-(boolean)%20Flag%20to): `Timeout in seconds before an abandoned(in use) connection can be removed. The default value is 60 (60 seconds). The value should be set to the longest running query your applications might have.`